# How do I make it show a picture in an embedded message on discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been trying to make a .avatar command but whenever I type .avatar it displays the embedded message, but it doesn't show a picture instead it shows just the URL. How do I make it that it shows the picture?'

```
let avatarEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setDescription(message.author.username)
  .addField("Avatar", message.author.avatarURL)

return message.reply(avatarEmbed)
```

Comment: `.setImage(message.author.avatarURL)`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RichEmbed.setImage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setImage) to set the image of a rich embed.

Also, I always suggest using [`User.displayAvatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=displayAvatarURL) instead of [`User.avatarURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=avatarURL); the latter will be `undefined` when the user has no avatar and causes issues in some cases, while the former would return the default avatar that's actually displayed.

```js
let avatarEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL)
  .setDescription(message.author.username);

return message.reply(avatarEmbed);
```